# JWT expiration time not being set correctly when using "7d" (7 days) duration

Tags: javascript, express, authentication

I'm facing an issue with setting the expiration time for JSON Web Tokens (JWTs) in my Node.js application. I have a function generateAuthToken that generates a JWT token with an expiration time based on a parameter called doNotLogout. If doNotLogout is true, I want the token to be valid for 7 days ("7d"), otherwise, I want it to be valid for 7 hours ("7h").

Here's my code for generateAuthToken:

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const generateAuthToken = (_id, name, lastName, email, isAdmin, doNotLogout) => {
  const expiresIn = doNotLogout ? "7d" : "7h";
  return jwt.sign(
    { _id, name, lastName, email, isAdmin },
    process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY,
    { expiresIn: expiresIn }
  );
};

module.exports = { generateAuthToken };
```

And here's the code for the loginUser function that utilizes generateAuthToken:

```
const loginUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { email, password, doNotLogout } = req.body;
    if (!email || !password)
      res.status(400).json({ error: "All input fields are required" });
    const user = await User.findOne({ email: email }).orFail();
    if (user && comparePasswords(password, user.password)) {
      let cookieParams = {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
        sameSite: "strict",
      };
      if (doNotLogout) {
        cookieParams = { ...cookieParams, maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 };
      }
      return res
        .cookie(
          "access_token",
          generateAuthToken(
            user._id,
            user.firstname,
            user.lastName,
            user.email,
            user.isAdmin,
            user.doNotLogout
          ),
          cookieParams
        )
        .status(200)
        .json({
          _id: user._id,
          name: user.firstname,
          lastName: user.lastName,
          email: user.email,
          isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
          doNotLogout,
        });
    } else {
      res.status(401).json({ error: "Wrong Credentials" });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};
```

The problem I'm facing is that the expiration time is not being set correctly. Even when doNotLogout is true, the token seems to expire after 7 hours instead of 7 days.

I have checked that the expiresIn variable is being set correctly based on the doNotLogout parameter. I'm using the jsonwebtoken library and following the documentation to set the expiration time. However, the token always expires after 7 hours.

I'm unsure what could be causing this issue. Could it be a problem with the library version or something else in my code? I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions to help me resolve this problem.

I have verified that the doNotLogout flag is correctly passed and that the expiresIn variable is assigned the correct value based on the flag's value.
The access token is stored in a cookie, but despite its presence, the JWT itself expires, causing authorization failures.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code and everything is fine, if the doNotLogout is true or 1 the token is valid for 7 days and if it is false or 0 the token is valid for 7 hours. I think you have to check your generated token [here](https://jwt.io/) and see the 'exp' in the payload section like this : [jwt decoder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1TG2.png)

If this problem still happens you can specify the node js version and jsonwebtoken version you use for more specific troubleshooting.

Comment: I figured out what went wrong, and it turned out to be a silly mistake on my part. Instead of sending the "doNotLogout" field from the request body, I accidentally passed a non-existent "donotlogout" key from the user object. By default, the "doNotLogout" attribute is set to false, which caused the expiration time to always be set to 7 hours.

Comment: congrats, maybe next time you can be more thorough in writing the variable name